# How could I know when someone attaches a removable disk on my computer?

Tags: c++, windows-xp, detect, removable-storage

I would like to know how can I detect when the user attaches a removable drive on a computer ( in a Windows XP environment ) . There surely has to be a better way than constantly checking to see if the number of drives increased , right ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's unlikely anyone will answer, I'll just do my part to back-link humanity's knowledge.

[Thís thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783657/get-notification-when-a-new-drive-is-connected-via-usb-or-other-means-c) seems to reference a few different ways:

1. [WM_DEVICECHANGE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/wm-devicechange?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
2. [Creating a windows service](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program)